# How to programmatically find device configurations?

Tags: android, configuration

Is there a way to find the device current configurations, like screen size and density, locale , region etc...

What I'm looking after is what the android does at runtime when selecting the right resource for the device current configuration, but I want to be able to download resources from my server.

is there a way? I know density I can find, what about the rest?

Answer (score 1):

```
        Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
               int h = d.getHeight();
               int w = d.getWidth();
    // This will give u screen width and height          


     LocationManager myLocationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Location myLocation = null;
    if(myLocation == null) // if Default Location is Null
                {
                    myLocation = myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                }
                if(myLocation!=null)
                {
                    String myLatitude = Location.convert(myLocation.getLatitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);

                    String myLongitude = Location.convert(myLocation.getLongitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);
                }

// You have to add "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" and "android.permission.INTERNET" permissions
```

Comment: thats not what I was looking for exactly.  I found some of the configurations on The Configuration object I get with `getResources().getConfiguration()` but for some reason config.screenLayout, isn't one of 'SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE/SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL/ SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL ' as it should